# Why doesn’t the sentence "the standard of proof being one based on balance of probabilities" contain a verb?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, inflectional-morphology, sentence-fragments, absolute-constructions

> The burden of proof is easier to discharge in a civil cases than in a criminal case, **the standard of proof being one based on balance of probabilities**.

Why there is no verb in the latter sentence? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Compare _She raced along the beach, her hair flying in the wind._ (This absolute clause adds further detail only.) // _Manchester Hotspurs may still qualify for the Champions League, their remaining fixtures being easier on paper than their rivals'._ (This absolute clause, like that in the original, adds an explanation to justify or at least bolster the assertion made in the main clause.)

Comment: Thx so much ^^.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one sentence in your example. The text after the comma, *the standard of proof being one based on balance of probabilities*, contains the non-finite verb *being*.

Such constructions are often called *absolute clauses*, defined as follows by *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p4):

> **Absolute clause**: A non-finite or verbless clause containing its own subject, attached
>   to the sentence from which it is separated by a comma, (or commas),
>   and not introduced by a subordinator. Also called an *absolute
>   construction*.

In this case, the subject of the absolute clause is *the standard of proof* and the sentence as a whole is grammatical.

Comment: Wouldn't all of "the standard of proof" be the subject with the clause being roughly equivalent to the sentence "the standard of proof is one based on balance of probabilities"?

Comment: CJ Dennis. You are right. It was an oversight to leave out _of proof_. I have amended my answer accordingly. Thanks.